# Nested boost::unordered_map does not update the value?

Tags: nested, unordered-map

The Code:

```
    boost::unordered_map<int, boost::unordered_map<int, float>> map;
{
    boost::unordered_map<int, float> h;
    h.insert(make_pair(1, 0.5));
    map.insert(make_pair(5, h));
}
{
    boost::unordered_map<int, float> h = map[5];
    h.insert(make_pair(2, 0.6));
    map.insert(make_pair(5, h));
}
cout << map[5].size() << endl;
```

Why the output is 1 not 2?
And when i use boost::unordered_map* > instead, then everything works well.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what happens in the second block of code:

1. `h = map[5]` creates a *copy* of the inner map.
2. `h.insert(...)` adds a value to the *copy* of the inner map.
3. `map.insert(...)` does nothing.  [unordered_map::insert inserts an element to the map if and only if there is no element in the map with an equivalent key](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html#id3724474-bb). But the key 5 is already present, and so no insertion happens. You can confirm this by checking that the boolean portion of the return value from the *insert* call is *false*.

At the end of the block, the copied map is discarded, and the original inner map, with a single value, remains in `map`. As a result, you get the output of *map[5].size()==1*.

But why do we get an output of 2 if the value type of the inner map is set to a pointer, `boost::unordered_map<int, float>*`? The second block of code would do this:

1. `h = map[5]` will get a pointer to the inner map inserted into `map`.
2. `h.insert(...)` adds a value to the inner map directly -- not into a copy. At this point, *map[5].size()==2* already.
3. `map.insert(...)` still does nothing. But there's no need to -- the inner map was already modified in place.

Comment: Exactly the right ans.And i also find that use map[i][j] we can easily do the same thing as pointer does.And with in my simple test, they equal in efficiency.So what is difference in ([][], insert, emplace).I know that the last two will not do anything if the key exist.And more differences?